# Will Apple Store employees activate my new iPhone?

Tags: iphone, unlock, apple-store, applecare

I bought a SIM FREE( Unlocked) **iPhone 6s** from the Apple Store in Glendale the other day.

The reason I used more money to get the SIM free one is because I'm here in L.A for a little vacation, but I live in another country. What I wanted was to use my new phone to take photos, use wifi, but it turns out I can't if I don't insert a valid SIM card.

I tried everything: cutting the SIM card I had in my old phone (*from another country*), connecting the phone to iTunes, searching if other people ever had the same problem, but nothing!

If I go to the Apple Store and ask them to activate it any way they can, will they? Does anyone know what I should do? I really want to use the phone, I thought the hardest part would be to save the money to buy it, how funny it is that now that I have it in my hands I can't do anything with it?

Please help me activate?

Comment: What happened when you connected iPhone to PC with iTunes installed ?

Comment: It's always the same, it tells me to insert the sim card. And when i insert the sim i cut(i made disasters but still) it tells me to please insert a valid sim card without a pin lock(what does that mean!!)

Comment: Just go to Walmart or anywhere that sells phone and buy a prepaid SIM card and stick it in.  SIM cards are easy to find.

Comment: Since i don't live here in the States i don't know much..so how much would that prepaid sim cost? And would i have to like fill in information or something? As i said before i don't live here so that's inpossible. They just give me a sim with a phone number or how does this work? And can i buy one prepaid for 1 week? Since that's how long i'll stay here.

Answer (score 1):

Camila, you can give Apple a call regarding your issue and they will fix it for you I believe. I've had my new iPad locked for a few months. I called them up from my country Bangladesh and then they asked me some security related questions. Within 24 hours my iPad was unlocked. Hope it helps. You can also go to the Apple Store and see if they can help. You might need to bring your purchase receipt.